# How to compressed folder that contain files in it ?

Tags: android

I have some folder that i need to compress before sending it by mail. 
I don't know how to make the compression of it before the mail send.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you would be interested in [Java Directory Zipping](http://www.crazysquirrel.com/computing/java/basics/java-directory-zipping.jspx).

I often use class ZipUtility of it when need to zip folders.